# Gamescene does not have a member named "waitEvent" error

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am currently learning Apple's new software programming language (Swift) and I have encountered this error:
Gamescene does not have a member named "waitEvent"
This is becoming quite frustrating, if anyone knows why this might be please respond.

This is in Swift and Sprite Kit!

Here is the code:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */    

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if (destroyerNode? != nil){
            destroyerNode!.position = location
            destroyerNode!.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
            destroyerNode!.physicsBody?.dynamic = true

            let waitAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(2)
            destroyerNode!.runAction(waitAction, completion: {
                self.waitEvent()
                //there is an issue with someEvent
                }
            )
        }
        else{
            println("that destroyer was really not there")
        }
    }

    func waitEvent(){
        //make the destroyer a dynamic object
        destroyerNode!.makeBodyDynamic()
        println("The wait is up")
    }

    func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you intentionally place waitEvent() and update() in touchesBegan()? Also, you need to override the SKScene's update() function.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that update was in touchesBegan, but at the time it wasn't causing problems that I knew of so I sort of ignored it. Also it told me I needed to override the update function when I moved it out of touchesBegan, anyway my question is what is overriding?

Comment: Overriding allows you to replace a super class's method in your subclass. For example, you can override SKScene's update method in your game scene to update your scene. The update method is called once per frame.